# BigQuery: How to filter out nulls from ARRAYS of STRUCT

Tags: arrays, struct, google-bigquery, null, unnest

I am having trouble getting my SQL in BigQuery to work when my query contains nulls in an ARRAY of STRUCT.  Here is the error I'm getting:

`Array cannot have a null element; error in writing field permissions.p.accts; error in writing field permissions.p; error in writing field permissions`

I have seen the [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg) for the `ARRAY_AGG` function which suggests using the `IGNORE NULLS` option, but as far as I can tell, this only works on arrays of scalar values, not on arrays of objects (ARRAY of STRUCT). I have tried a number of different approaches to using the ARRAY_AGG function, and I can't get it to work in the following scenario.  So I'm looking for a solution that will allow my query to work even when there are nulls (see the second example below).

Here is an example query that works fine:

```
with example as (
  select JSON '{"permissions":{"p":[{"accts":["abc"],"perms":["def"]}]}}' as json_data
)

select STRUCT( 
          ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT 
                  JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(permission,'$.accts') as accts,
                  JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(permission,'$.perms') as perms
                FROM UNNEST(
                            JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(example.json_data, '$.permissions.p')
                          ) as permission
                ) as p 
             ) as permissions
from example
;
```

Now here is an example of the same query with a null value, and it throws the error mentioned above.  The only difference in this query is that the `"accts":["abc"]` has been changed to `"accts":[null]`.

```
with example as (
  select JSON '{"permissions":{"p":[{"accts":[null],"perms":["def"]}]}}' as json_data
)

select STRUCT( 
          ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT 
                  JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(permission,'$.accts') as accts,
                  JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(permission,'$.perms') as perms
                FROM UNNEST(
                            JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(example.json_data, '$.permissions.p')
                          ) as permission
                ) as p 
             ) as permissions
from example
;
```

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After parsing the JSON and obtaining the array, this array needs to be unnested and filtered to eliminate the null entries. This can be done in a user function UDF or in a subSelect.

```
Create temp function JSON_VALUE_ARRAY_no_NULL(ARR any type, str string)
as 
 (( SELECT X from UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(ARR ,str )) X WHERE X IS NOT NULL ))
;
with example as (
  select JSON '{"permissions":{"p":[{"accts":["abc"],"perms":["def"]}]}}' as json_data
  union all select JSON '{"permissions":{"p":[{"accts":[null],"perms":["def"]}]}}' 
)

select STRUCT( 
          ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT 
                  (( SELECT X from UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(permission ,'$.accts' )) X WHERE X IS NOT NULL )) as accts,
                  JSON_VALUE_ARRAY_no_NULL(permission ,'$.accts' ) as accts3,
                  JSON_VALUE_ARRAY_no_NULL(permission,'$.perms') as perms
                FROM UNNEST(
                            JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(example.json_data, '$.permissions.p')
                          ) as permission
                ) as p 
             ) as permissions
from example
```